# Service specific error code 1 using tomcat 8 as a windows service

Tags: tomcat, service

I have installed Tomcat v8.5.73 as a windows service using the following command:

```
CATALINA_HOME/bin> tomcat8 //IS//Tomcat8 --DisplayName="MyService"
```

But when I try to start the service from windows services app (As administrator) it shows the following error

> Windows could not start the MyService on local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1

I also tried stating the service the following way:

```
CATALINA_HOME/bin> startup
```

This worked but I had to allow access to private/public networks (Don't remember which one).

Here is some additional information:

1. I have CATALINA_HOME set as an environment variable
2. I have Java_HOME set as an environment variable, I am using java v1.8.0_311
3. JVM is 64-bit HotSpot(TM)
4. I have only one version of java installed on my pc.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: So what does the System Event Log show? Actually that would be an interesting info that could help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recommended](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services) way to install Tomcat8.5 as a service is to open a command prompt as administrator, then `cd %TOMCAT_HOME%\bin`, and run `service.bat install`.  This script provides many more parameters.  (In a cmd bat script, ^ before newline continues a command on the next line.)